# DataTables column().search() - Search by beginning letters in string

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a column search for Surnames.

In the 'Search Surname' textbox in the table footer, I want to be able to search so as I type "S"..."i"..."m".."p" the results still appear for "Simpson", but not if I type "son", for example.

At the moment if I type "son", the "Simpson" results still appear as the text is contained in the string.

How do I configure it to search the beginning of the string as I type?

Here is my code so far:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.thSurname').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search Surname" />');
    });

    var table = $('#ContactTable').DataTable({
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bVisible": false },
            { "sClass": "center" },
            { "sClass": "center" },
            { "sClass": "center" },
            { "sClass": "center" }
        ]
    });

    table.columns().eq(0).each(function (colIdx) {
        $('input', table.column(colIdx).footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column(colIdx)
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
.search(new RegExp("^"+this.value,"i")).
```

The carrot symbol means to only match expressions that come at the beginning of the searched string.  The `i` modifier means it's case insensitive.

A quick [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E49SL/) shows it works for me.

Comment: I've just tried that with no joy. Console error page says "i is not defined"

Comment: @user1612185 oops, the `i` should be a string, I revised my answer.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: The option above works, but only if you are searching per column. 


so 


`$('#elementName').dataTable().search('^'+searchStr, true, false).draw();`



will fail to find results, but....



`$('#elementName').dataTable().column(1).search('^'+searchStr, true, false).draw();`



will find the beginning of the column, even if multiple word string.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions here didn't seem to work for me perhaps it's deprecated code. I ended up using the fnFilter funtion. e.g. :

```
$('.datatable').dataTable().fnFilter("^" + text, 0, true);
```

or for text starting with numbers:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable().fnFilter("^[0-9]", 0, true);
```

and then to clear the filter

```
$('.datatable').dataTable().fnFilter("", 0);
```